# TinyMCE Image Upload Not Working on iOS (Safari)

Tags: ios, image, safari, upload, tinymce

I've enabled image upload on TinyMCE using the [images_upload_url](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/file-image-upload/#images_upload_url) parameter. This works fine in most browsers, but it does not work on Safari in iOS.

```
tinymce.init({
  images_upload_url: '/uploadImage'
  automatic_uploads: true
});
```

I've noticed, first of all, that the "Browse for an image" button on the Upload tab is positioned on top of the file input (which has an opacity of zero); and the file input click event is not getting triggered. In addition, TinyMCE's event handler on the file input seems to be preventing Safari from opening the file selection dialog.

Has anyone else seen this problem, and is there a workaround?

Comment: Hey, did you manage to find a solution to the file input click not getting triggered?

Answer (score 1):

I realise this is a dated question but I'll leave this here for anyone who needs it should their requirement be with TinyMCE 4 without mobile enabled.

iOS safari does not behave nicely on click events being bound on non clickable elements. [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event#safari_mobile) gives a good explanation.
TinyMCE use a div element to fire a click event (from looking through the source code).

So you need to add a touchend event handler to the button element yourself.
You also need to hook into the [dialog OpenWindow and CloseWindow events](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/advanced/events/#editorcoreevents) on the editor so that you can add the touchend event and clean up.

```
tinyMCE.init({
      selector: selector,
      plugins: "paste,link,image",
      toolbar: "undo redo | bold italic underline | link image",
      file_picker_types: 'image',
      images_upload_handler: image_upload_handler,
      automatic_uploads: true,
      setup : function(editor){
           editor.on('OpenWindow', function(e){
                $('.mce-browsebutton button').on('touchend', function(event) {
                    $(this).click(); 
                });
            });
            editor.on('CloseWindow', function(e){
                 $('.mce-browsebutton button').off('touchend');
            });
         }        
    });
```

Otherwise you can use the mobile mode (note that this is for TinyMCE 4 (v5 is set up different so refer to their [docs](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/mobile/))

```
tinyMCE.init({
    selector: selector,
    mobile: {
      theme: 'mobile'
    },
    plugins: "paste,link,image",
    toolbar: "undo redo | bold italic underline | link image",
    file_picker_types: 'image',
    images_upload_handler: image_upload_handler,
    automatic_uploads: true
});
```

Comment: Thanks the first bit of code solved a headache in my Wordpress theme with a front end editor allowing image uploads. Before, in iOS, the only way for the button to respond was to click the 1 px border